# Why is select box defaulting to scroll in WordPress admin panel instead of drop down?

Tags: css, wordpress, styles, wordpress-theming

I'm making a theme specific admin panel in WordPress. I've run into a problem when using the select tag though and I know I don't have any styles that are making it behave this way:

[image]

This is not a screen shot of my panel but this is a good example. See the box on the top left? Well anytime I use a select box it defaults to scroll mode like that one in the picture. I don't want it to do that. I want it to be a regular drop down list box like the other 3 in the image. I can't figure out if this is a CSS problem or not. I have checked out a few resources about select boxes but none of them mention anything about a type attribute of select tags or anything that would let me change out of scroll mode. Is there some kind of built in wordpress style that changes the way the select tags are rendered in the admin panel? If so how do I style this element so that it is just a regular drop down list box? Here is the code that I'm using for the select:

```
<select name="slide_type" size="30">
                        <option>Slice Down</option>
                        <option>Slice Down Left</option>
                        <option>Slice Up</option>
                        <option>Slice Up Left</option>
                        <option>Slice Down</option>
                        <option>Slice Up & Down</option>
                        <option>Slice Up & Down Left</option>
                        <option>Fold</option>
                    </select>
```

Note: I've checked in firebug and there are no styles attached to this drop down list or it's name - "slide_type" other than the following CSS:

```
select{
   color: black;
}
```

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a bare-bones version of this entire panel plugin?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TguQDc0LqRDT6GuE64vnpfZM07vPawy2-OTfnSWIy8M/edit try that and let me know if it works. I've never done it this way before. The select tag is highlighted in bright green.

Comment: Ah, you put this in functions.php as part of your theme, right?

Comment: Oh you're from Baltimore? I'm from Frederick. Small world.

Comment: You're from Serbia? I'm from Bosnia. Smaller world.

Comment: Hahaha, no I just put that on my facebook as a joke with a friend. Thanks for trying to help me though man. I got the answer now but thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's the size value, of course.

use

```
   size=1
```

(or leave it undefined)

And get a [free silly demo](http://jsfiddle.net/62LGJ/) too!

Comment: Thanks man. I thought the size attribute was doing the same thing as the size attribute on text inputs, specifically extending the length of the box... I don't know why I thought that.

Comment: Yeah, its counter-intuitive. I almost wrote a note about it.